# Which Machine Learning model to choose for n Number recommendations based of input numeric parameters

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

We want to develop a Machine Learning based recommendation model. Our data-set has about 25 numeric input parameters and an output parameter (Lender). Based on the input parameters we want machine learning model to recommend n number of best lenders.

Here is the Sample Data with few input attributes and LENDER (Output parameter).

```
M_Year  B_Age V_Score   C_Type  F_Amount    Terms   F_Product   V_Type      LENDER
2019    20      150     1       15000       12      1           1           Lender-A
2019    30      250     2       25000       36      3           3           Lender-B
2019    20      150     3       35000       24      2           2           Lender-C
2019    20      150     1       10000       48      5           4           Lender-D
```

Please advise which machine learning model can fulfill our requirement?
We want to use sklearns or AWS Sagemaker. But unable to decide which algorithm to use.